# Finding %ebp after crash (have %eip)

Tags: c, x86

I am writing a crash back trace program for a course. The provided starter code gives us %eip upon a crash, and we are supposed to print the backtrace of the runtime stack.

The first step seems to be to get %ebp of the top stack, and our assignment says that there is "something accessible in C code that has a guaranteed fixed location relative to the current base pointer".

The only thing I can think of would be the arguments to a function being stored at a fixed location above %ebp, but I cannot think of any possible way to use this information.

What is a way to find this %ebp with just C code (no inline assembly or anything)?

Any ponting in the right direction would be much appreciated! I'm on x86-32 bit.

Comment: Just to make sure, is this x86 or x86-64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that task is given for Linux/UNIX.

> The provided starter code gives us %eip upon a crash,

So, you are now in the SIGSEGV handler and have eip from.... context - the third parameter of handler?

First way:

The signal handler is started on the stack of application; and if you will take address of some local variable, you will get pointer to the stack:

```
 void sigsegv_handler(int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *context)
 {
   int a;
   void * ptr = &a;
   void * ptr_epb = ptr+0x**; 
   // 0x** is an unknown offset, find in disassembly or in debugger
 }
```

This is not generally "guaranteed fixed location relative to the current base pointer" if we are talking about generalized case (according to C programming language standard and/or some  UNIX Specification this should be undefined behaviour). But for x86/x86_64; some fixed compiler; fixed set of compiler options; enabled  frame pointer saving in stack, then this offset will be constant.

Second way:

Check ucontext.h (/usr/include/sys) and hack into it via third argument to handler.

Comment: I suspect the assignment assumes the function parameters are at fixed offsets from %ebp. This would be more reliable than the address of a local variable. Neither is guaranteed by the C standard, of course, but the compiler is quite likely to rearrange local variables for various reasons and less likely to move parameters. The original parameter locations generally are determined by an application binary interface for the platform, so they **must** be in certain locations. This does not guarantee that the compiler makes them visible at those locations when taking their addresses, though.

Comment: Alternate methods of getting %ebp include inline assembly (just move %ebp to the desired place) and, very simply, the GCC builtin for exactly this purpose, `__builtin_frame_address(level)`.

Comment: Eric, are parameters allowed to be passed on the registers? What will be if they are and I'm taking address of parameter?

Comment: The publisher of an application binary interface (ABI) may specify where parameters are passed, and that may be in registers or elsewhere. Generally, the manufacturer of a machine or the publisher of an operating system specifies an ABI. Sometimes a compiler implementation may provide a different ABI (which makes interaction with operating system libraries troublesome). Once the ABI is adopted, there is generally no choice about where parameters are passed; the ABI must be obeyed. Many ABIs specify that registers are used for the first few normal-size parameters, then stack is used.

Comment: When you take the address of a parameter that is passed in a register, the compiler must make a copy of it in memory. There may be wide variation in where that copy is made, from compiler to compiler, from version to version, even from routine to routine. So the address of a parameter is also not a reliable way to find the frame pointer.

Answer (score 1):

In GCC, use `__builtin_frame_address(level)`. See [this page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html). Any attempt to find %ebp through standard C constructions is likely a hack that is not guaranteed to work.